# Formula referencing cells as index not working

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet made up of 2 sheets.

The first sheet is just data that has been imported.

The second sheet is a number of formulas that will extract various counts and totals from the first sheet.

The first formula is as follows

```
=COUNTIFS(Raw_data!B2:B1780,"Y7",Raw_data!F2:F1780,"M",Raw_data!G2:G1780,"D",Raw_data!L2:L1780,"EN")
```

It looks at 4 columns in the first sheet and counts the number of records that meet the criteria in each column.

This works fine. However, the number of rows in the raw data (1780) could vary. I have a found a formula that works out the number of rows in the raw data and that works OK. So what I was trying to do, was instead of having the number of rows fixed at 1780, have the above formula get the the number of rows from the cell that has done the row calculation. 
So I ended up with this

```
=COUNTIFS(Raw_data!B2:INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",G3)),"Y7",Raw_data!F2:F1780,"F",Raw_data!G2:G1780,"D",Raw_data!L2:L1780,"EN")
```

where G3 contains the calculated number of rows. (I've only done this for raw data column B at present, as I wanted to prove it first). Excel comes back with #VALUE! in the formula cell, no matter what variations I try. I suspect the answer is very simple, but at present it eludes me.

Comment: You can just use the `&` operator. e.g. `"A1:"&G3`. No need of `CONCATENATE()`

Comment: GalAbra did you mean like this?
=COUNTIFS(Raw_data!"B2:"&G3,"Y7",Raw_data!F2:F1780,"M",Raw_data!G2:G1780,"DAY",Raw_data!L2:L1780,"ENROLLED")
It now says "Error in formula", shouldn't I have a B in front of the "&G3 somwhere?
pnuts how do mean whole column references?
Many thanks

Comment: Sorry, should have also said, one file, two sheets, so Raw_data is always open at the same time as formulas sheet.

Comment: Just occurred me what problem might be, the range B2:B1780 is on the first sheet (raw_data), but the reference cell G3 is on the second (formula) sheet, I therefore wonder if it's referring to G3 on the data sheet?